# UTC time is different to actual UTC time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to check the UTC time in JavaScript.

But I found that UTC  time in JavaScript (using "(new Date()).toISOString()") is 2:31 minute ahead from actual UTC time.

This feature creating problems for me. I am using CakePHP. In the template, I created JavaScript variable to store the created DateTime of the record. And using that variable to calculate the time difference in JavaScript. But its calculating wrong result.

Is it possible to display Actual UTC time in JavaScript? Or is there any solution for this?

NOTE: I also tried moment and facing the same issue.

[image: UTC-Time difference IMAGE]

Comment: `is 2:31 minute ahead from actual UTC time` ... no it isn't, it's either something else in your code or your PC has the wrong time

Comment: @JaromandaX it's mostly likely the latter.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the reply, But same issues occurring in others colleague PCs

Comment: not if you look at the picture - must be something in the code that retards the time on the display - whose to say which one is right

Comment: well ... you'll need to show the **code** that creates the clock in that picture - it is probably wrong ... the fact that you and your colleagues have the same issue suggests it's your code that is at fault - but as you've shared none, that's just a wild speculation

Comment: @JaromandaX This is a live site. https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc
google also showing same time

Comment: @user3292290 - perfectly in synch on my computer - must be something at your end

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, I found My System time is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX

Comment: so how is it that yours and your colleagues computer had the same issue?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, my and my colleagues system time is wrong. I matched my system time with google's current time (using my actual TimeZone), My system time 2:31 minutes ahead from actual time.

Comment: Likely you and your colleague's computers are synchronized to the same time source, and that time source is out of sync with UTC.  For example, if you're at a university or corporation, you're probably on a domain.  The domain controller would keep time in sync for the computers on the domain, but if the administrator of the domain controller has just set the time manually instead of synchronizing it with another reliable time source, then it could be in error, or drift over time, and that difference would propagate to all computers on the domain.